# Why is $(</dev/fd/0) not much faster than $(cat)?

Tags: performance, bash, input, stdin, cat

Debian's Bash manual suggest using the special command substitution `$(< file)` whenever `$(cat file)` would be required, for the sake of performance, avoiding the execution of an external binary.

However, the measured completion time for the following code is about the same:

```
time for i in {0..1000}; do echo str | { in=$(cat); }; done
time for i in {0..1000}; do echo str | { in=$(< /dev/fd/0); }; done
```

Over a few runs, they consistently return values around these figures, respectively:

```
real    0m3.665s
user    0m0.365s
sys     0m0.782s
```

and

```
real    0m2.401s
user    0m0.233s
sys     0m0.533s
```

So the improvement of command substitution over `cat` is largely negligible for most use cases. Since my script needs to quickly and cyclically read large amounts of stdin, what can I do to accelerate these readings? In particular, the whole stream of stdin data needs to be dumped into a Bash variable for further *parameter substitutions*.

**Further testing:**

After the comments below and further testing, I set 10,000 iterations instead of 1000 <s>to minimize the pipe setup overhead</s>, and I deleted the brackets for the *compound command* syntax:

```
$ time for i in {1..10000}; do echo str | in=$(cat); done

real    0m24.754s
user    0m6.958s
sys     0m18.996s

$ time for i in {1..10000}; do echo str | in=$(< /dev/fd/0); done

real    0m33.913s
user    0m3.736s
sys     0m10.516s
```

Here I am unable to explain why `$(< /dev/fd/0)` is even slower now.

Comment: I'm confused. Your benchmark shows a 33% speedup.

Comment: ...and that quick benchmark is largely measuring the time needed to set up a pipeline, as opposed to the performance of reading stdin. Maybe if you showed us your *actual* code, we could try to help with optimizing it, but as it is, the numbers you're seeing look eminently reasonable.

Comment: For an integrated Bash call I was expecting something largely below the millisecond.

Comment: @davide, but you're doing much more than just calling a builtin in this code. You're setting up a pipeline! Pipelines are expensive!

Comment: @davide, that is to say, you should also measure the performance of `time for i in {0..1000}; do echo str | true; done`, to measure the other components of what this code is doing, and consider that a baseline.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, ...so it's actually closer to a 3x speedup when factoring out constant-time costs.

Comment: I get your point. I measured the same code over 10.000 cycles instead of the original 1000. The figures I get are approx 34 seconds for `cat` and 30 for `$(<)`, so the overhead to set up the pipe seems the minor among the other costs.

Comment: re: "the other costs" -- if you haven't done that same test with `true` (no reading stdin at all), then you don't know how much goes into them.

Comment: If performance is an issue, why are you using `bash` at all?

Comment: Indeed. Even if one wanted to use a shell language, ksh93 (real David Korne ksh, not the clones) is far, far faster. And as much as I despise it for its intentional noncompliance with POSIX, so is zsh.

Comment: How do you think increasing the number of iterations decreases that overhead? You're still setting up a pipeline once per iteration, since the pipeline is _inside_ your loop. Decreasing the brackets is irrelevant -- it's the thousands of subshells for the thousands of pipelines that are expensive.

Comment: Holy cow, that's true! I didn't realize the pipe was being created over each iteration. Moving the pipe out of the loop, after `done`, terribly improves performance. So yes, the pipe is an expensive gadget.

Answer (score 3):

You're forgetting to factor out performance costs unrelated to reading from stdin (the costs of fork()ing to create a subshell, setting up a pipeline, wait()ing for those processes to exit, etc).

```
$ time for i in {0..1000}; do echo str | { in=$(cat); }; done
real    0m3.183s
user    0m1.427s
sys     0m2.486s

$ time for i in {0..1000}; do echo str | { in=$(< /dev/fd/0); }; done
real    0m1.973s
user    0m0.917s
sys     0m1.844s

$ time for i in {0..1000}; do echo str | true; done
real    0m1.294s
user    0m0.708s
sys     0m1.367s
```

Thus:

- Using `$(cat)` adds approximately (3.183s - 1.294s == 1.889s) wall-clock time over 1000 iterations, compared to the code that does all other setup but doesn't read stdin.
- Using `$(</dev/fd/0)` adds approximately (1.972s - 1.294s == 0.697s) over 1000 iterations.

This is a 2.7x improvement, and well under the 1ms per invocation you expect.